# Get the first child node using the Internet Explorer COM object

Tags: com, autohotkey, getelementbyid

I got a website with the following code:

```html
<div id="past">
<div data-rollid="99999" class="ball kugel-2">2</div>
<div data-rollid="99998" class="ball kugel-2">2</div>
<div data-rollid="99997" class="ball kugel-2">2</div>
```

I want to get this number "2". I know that I can pickup the "past" by
`past := wb.document.getElementById("past")`
but how to get the value from the first child node?

Comment: You really should attempt to explain what you did, what you tried, and what results you are getting.  I don't see a lot of AHK code in your post?  Do you know about `.innerText` for retrieving the InnerHTML in AHK?

Comment: @PGilm As I see it this question is about javascript and not autohotkey, correct?

Comment: .innerText is not specific to AHK and not the same as .innerHTML (both are available in the COM object and can be accessed using AHK). Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give a lot to work with, but you might try, for the first "undertag":

```
    wb.Document.getElementByID("past").childnodes.item[0].innerText
```

For the second "undertag":

```
    wb.Document.getElementByID("past").childnodes.item[1].innerText
```

etc.

Else, look at something like this:

```
    wb.document.body.querySelector("data-rollid='99998']").innerText;
```

or

```
    wb.document.getElementByID("past").querySelector("data-rollid='99998']").innerText;
```

or even

```
    wb.document.getElementByID("past").childnodes.querySelector("data-rollid='99998']").innerText;
```

Which might work (you might have to play around with the syntax) . . .

Hth,

Answer (score 0):

This can get you all the elements of a certain class:

```
elements:=ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ball kugel-2")
```

Or you can do this:

```
past:= wb.document.getElementById("past")
children:=past.children
while(a_index <= children.length, i:=a_index-1)
     msgbox, % children[i].innertext
```